# Relay throw error: Cannot read property 'reduce' of undefined

Tags: reactjs, sequelize.js, graphql, relayjs, relay

I'm trying to create a load more function to my simple application. I fetch data from MySQL using Sequelize and GraphQL. I use relay-starter-kit as the scaffolding for my application.

**database.js**

```
import Sequelize from 'sequelize';
import _ from 'lodash';
import Faker from 'faker';

const Conn = new Sequelize('relay', 'root', '', {
  host: 'localhost',
  dialect: 'mysql'
});

const Person = Conn.define('person', {
  firstName: {
    type: Sequelize.STRING,
    allowNull: false
  },
  lastName: {
    type: Sequelize.STRING,
    allowNull: false
  },
  email: {
    type: Sequelize.STRING,
    allowNull: false,
    validate: {
      isEmail: true
    }
  },
  createdAt: {
    type: Sequelize.DATE,
    allowNull: false,
  },
  updatedAt: {
    type: Sequelize.DATE,
    allowNull: false,
  }
});

const Post = Conn.define('post', {
  title: {
    type: Sequelize.STRING,
    allowNull: false
  },
  content: {
    type: Sequelize.STRING,
    allowNull: false
  }
});

// Relationships
Person.hasMany(Post);
Post.belongsTo(Person);

Conn.sync({ force: true }).then(() => {
   _.times(10, () => {
     return Person.create({
       firstName: Faker.name.firstName(),
       lastName: Faker.name.lastName(),
       email: Faker.internet.email(),
       createdAt: Date.now(),
       updatedAt: Date.now()
     }).then(person => {
       return person.createPost({
         title: `Sample title by ${person.firstName}`,
         content: 'This is a sample article'
       });
     });
   })
 });

// Model types
class User { }

// Mock data
var viewer = new User();
viewer.id = '1';

module.exports = {
  // Export methods that your schema can use to interact with your database
  getUser: (id) => id === viewer.id ? viewer : null,
  getViewer: () => viewer,
  Conn
};
```

**schema.js**

```
import {
  GraphQLBoolean,
  GraphQLFloat,
  GraphQLID,
  GraphQLInt,
  GraphQLList,
  GraphQLNonNull,
  GraphQLObjectType,
  GraphQLSchema,
  GraphQLString,
} from 'graphql';

import {
  connectionArgs,
  connectionDefinitions,
  connectionFromArray,
  connectionFromPromisedArraySlice,
  connectionFromPromisedArray,
  fromGlobalId,
  globalIdField,
  mutationWithClientMutationId,
  nodeDefinitions,
} from 'graphql-relay';

import {
  // Import methods that your schema can use to interact with your database
  getUser,
  getViewer,
  Conn
} from './database';

/**
 * We get the node interface and field from the Relay library.
 *
 * The first method defines the way we resolve an ID to its object.
 * The second defines the way we resolve an object to its GraphQL type.
 */
var {nodeInterface, nodeField} = nodeDefinitions(
  (globalId) => {
    var {type, id} = fromGlobalId(globalId);
    if (type === 'User') {
      return getUser(id);
    } else {
      return null;
    }
  },
  (obj) => {
    if (obj instanceof User) {
      return userType;
    } else {
      return null;
    }
  }
);

/**
 * Define your own types here
 */

const Person = new GraphQLObjectType({
  name: "Person",
  description: "This represents a person",
  fields: () => {
    return {
      id: {
        type: GraphQLString,
        resolve(person) {
          return person.id
        }
      },
      firstName: {
        type: GraphQLString,
        resolve(person) {
          return person.firstName
        }
      },
      lastName: {
        type: GraphQLString,
        resolve(person) {
          return person.lastName
        }
      },
      email: {
        type: GraphQLString,
        resolve(person) {
          return person.email
        }
      },
      posts: {
        type: new GraphQLList(Post),
        resolve(person) {
          return person.getPosts();
        }
      }
    }
  }
});

const Post = new GraphQLObjectType({
  name: "Post",
  description: "This is a post",
  fields: () => {
    return {
      id: {
        type: GraphQLString,
        resolve(person) {
          return person.id;
        }
      },
      title: {
        type: GraphQLString,
        resolve(post) {
          return post.title;
        }
      },
      content: {
        type: GraphQLString,
        resolve(post) {
          return post.content;
        }
      },
      person: {
        type: Person,
        resolve(post) {
          return post.getPerson();
        }
      }
    }
  }
})

var userType = new GraphQLObjectType({
  name: 'User',
  description: 'A person who uses our app',
  fields: () => ({
    id: globalIdField('User'),
    people: {
      type: personConnection,
      description: 'A collection of persons',
      args: connectionArgs,
      resolve(_, args, info) {
        console.log("==== INFO ====");
        console.log(info);
        let gas = {};
        gas.first=  args.first;
        gas.after = args.after;
        gas.find = args.find;
        delete args.first;
        delete args.after;
        delete args.find;
        return connectionFromPromisedArray(Conn.models.person.findAll({ where: args }), gas);
      }
    },
  })
});

var {connectionType: personConnection} =
  connectionDefinitions({ name: 'Person', nodeType: Person });

/**
 * This is the type that will be the root of our query,
 * and the entry point into our schema.
 */
var queryType = new GraphQLObjectType({
  name: 'Query',
  description: "This is a root query",
  fields: () => ({
    node: nodeField,
    // Add your own root fields here
    viewer: {
      type: userType,
      resolve: () => getViewer(),
    }
  }),
});

/**
 * This is the type that will be the root of our mutations,
 * and the entry point into performing writes in our schema.
 */
var mutationType = new GraphQLObjectType({
  name: 'Mutation',
  fields: () => ({
    // Add your own mutations here
  })
});

/**
 * Finally, we construct our schema (whose starting query type is the query
 * type we defined above) and export it.
 */
export var Schema = new GraphQLSchema({
  query: queryType,
  types: [queryType, userType, Person, Post]
  // Uncomment the following after adding some mutation fields:
  // mutation: mutationType
});
```

**App.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import Relay from 'react-relay';
import AnimateOnChange from 'react-animate-on-change';

class Detail extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { person: [] };
  }
  componentWillMount() {
    this.setState({ person: this.props.person });
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h2>Selected User's Detail</h2>
        <div className="form-group">
          <label>User ID:</label>
          <p className="form-control">
            <AnimateOnChange
              baseClassName="animated"
              animationClassName="fadeIn"
              animate={true}>{this.props.person.id}</AnimateOnChange>
          </p>
        </div>
        <div className="form-group">
          <label>First Name</label>
          <p className="form-control">
            <AnimateOnChange
              baseClassName="animated"
              animationClassName="fadeIn"
              animate={true}>{this.props.person.firstName}</AnimateOnChange>
          </p>
        </div>
        <div className="form-group">
          <label>Last Name</label>
          <p className="form-control">
            <AnimateOnChange
              baseClassName="animated"
              animationClassName="fadeIn"
              animate={true}>{this.props.person.lastName}</AnimateOnChange>
          </p>
        </div>
        <h2>Selected User's Posts</h2>
        <table className="table table-hovered">
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <th>No</th>
              <th>Post ID</th>
              <th>Title</th>
              <th>Content</th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
            {this.props.person.posts.map((post, key) =>
              <tr key={post.id} className="animated fadeIn">
                <td>{key + 1}.</td>
                <td>{post.id} {post[key]}</td>
                <td>{post.title}</td>
                <td>{post.content}</td>
              </tr>
            ) }
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { index: 0 }
  }
  _handleClick(key) {
    if (this.state.index !== key) {
      this.setState({ index: key })
    }
  }
  _loadMore(){
    console.log(this.props.viewer.people);
    this.props.relay.setVariables({
      first: this.props.relay.variables.first,
      after: this.props.viewer.people.pageInfo.endCursor
    });
  }
  render() {
    console.log(this.props.viewer.people);
    return (
      <div className="container">
        <h2>Users List</h2>
        <button onClick={this._loadMore.bind(this)}>Load more</button>
        <ul className="list-group">
          {this.props.viewer.people.edges.map((p, key) =>
            <li className={key !== this.state.index ? "list-group-item" : "list-group-item active"} onClick={this._handleClick.bind(this, key) } key={p.node.id}>{p.node.firstName} {p.node.lastName} (ID: {p.node.id}) </li>
          ) }
        </ul>
        <Detail person={this.props.viewer.people.edges[this.state.index].node}/>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

export default Relay.createContainer(App, {
  fragments: {
    viewer: () => Relay.QL`
      fragment on User {
        people(first: $first, after: $after){
          edges{
            node{
              id,
              firstName,
              lastName,
              posts{
                id,
                title,
                content
              }              
            }
          }
          pageInfo{
            hasNextPage
            hasPreviousPage
            startCursor
            endCursor
          }
        }
      }
    `
  },
  initialVariables: {
    first: 3,
    after: null
  }
});
```

**AppHomeRoute.js**

```
import Relay from 'react-relay';

export default class extends Relay.Route {
  static queries = {
    viewer: (Component) => Relay.QL`
      query {
        viewer {
          ${Component.getFragment('viewer')}
        }
      }
    `,
  };
  static routeName = 'AppHomeRoute';
}
```

This application is simple. There is a button that when clicked, will trigger a 'load more' function. You can see the function in App.js. Whenever the function runs, it returns:

`Cannot read property 'reduce' of undefined`.

I've tried to make sure that the query is correct and I found something 'interesting' when I tried to make a query using GraphiQL.

If I use **fragment** (same as the application's way when making request to the server):

```
query App_ViewerRelayQL($id_0: ID!) {
  node(id: $id_0) {
    id
    ...F0
  }
}

fragment F0 on User {
  _people35G0DJ: people(after: "YXJyYXljb25uZWN0aW9uOjI=", first: 2) {
    edges {
      node {
        id
        firstName
        lastName
        posts {
          id
          title
          content
        }
      }
      cursor
    }
    pageInfo {
      hasNextPage
      hasPreviousPage
    }
  }
  id
}
```

**Result**:

```
{
  "errors": [
    {
      "message": "Cannot read property 'reduce' of undefined"
    }
  ]
}
```

If I **don't use fragment** (raw query):

```
query {
  viewer {
    id
    people(after:"YXJyYXljb25uZWN0aW9uOjE=",first:2) {
      edges {
        node {
          id
          firstName
          lastName
          posts {
            id
            title
            content
          }
        }
        cursor
      }
      pageInfo {
        hasNextPage
        hasPreviousPage
      }
    }
    id
  }
}
```

**Result**:

```
{
  "data": {
    "viewer": {
      "id": "VXNlcjox",
      "people": {
        "edges": [
          {
            "node": {
              "id": "3",
              "firstName": "Filomena",
              "lastName": "Ebert",
              "posts": [
                {
                  "id": "3",
                  "title": "Sample title by Filomena",
                  "content": "This is a sample article"
                }
              ]
            },
            "cursor": "YXJyYXljb25uZWN0aW9uOjI="
          },
          {
            "node": {
              "id": "4",
              "firstName": "Alessandra",
              "lastName": "Muller",
              "posts": [
                {
                  "id": "4",
                  "title": "Sample title by Alessandra",
                  "content": "This is a sample article"
                }
              ]
            },
            "cursor": "YXJyYXljb25uZWN0aW9uOjM="
          }
        ],
        "pageInfo": {
          "hasNextPage": true,
          "hasPreviousPage": false
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Suppose to be the problem is with the query, but I'm not sure. I'm getting a little bit frustrated right now. Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I would try to debug you _loadMore function a bit more to see if you're setting those variables properly.

```
_loadMore(){
  console.log(this.props.viewer.people);
  this.props.relay.setVariables({
    first: this.props.relay.variables.first,
    after: this.props.viewer.people.pageInfo.endCursor
  });
}
```

The only difference between in-lining the whole query versus using fragments is that you're passing in those query variables dynamically. So it seems like your `initialVariables` sets `after` to null, which may be causing the query to break on the GraphQL server side.